# IP configuration manager with control panel integration?

Tags: windows

I know there's a program like this out there, but what I'm looking for is essentially a much less clunky version of the Network and Sharing Center for Windows that has the ability to override the Network and Sharing Center. It also, when installed, had a link in the Control Panel that I swear I distinctly remember.

I used SOMETHING like this before, but I had to reimage the computer it was on and so forgot what the name of the program was, I just remember that it was amazingly detailed and much easier to use than the normal Network and Sharing Center.

Anyone kind of know what I'm talking about? I've got some pretty above-average knowledge of Windows so if you have big terms to toss out there, go ahead. And if no such thing exists, is there something similar?